# Missing wordpress civivolunteer commendation table

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, civivolunteer, multisite

We have wordpress 4.9.4 and civi volunteer 4.7.21-2.2.3

When someone makes a contribution or joins as a member, we get a missing table database error (from the error log):
Table 'vahcrm.civicrm_value_volunteer_commendation_7' doesn't exist

This error occurs after the transaction goes through and civi tries to update the database and the user gets the error:
Failed to update contribution in database

When we try to renew a membership, we get (from the error log):
Table 'vahcrm.civicrm_value_civivolunteer_5' doesn't exist

A little background....I'm a volunteer for a non-profit. The previous web/civi admin person moved everything to a new site, broke the site into a multi-site configuration without fully setting everything up, and then quit. I came to the civi problems having only heard the word civi before. I would appreciate ANY help I can get to figure this out.

How do I go about finding and fixing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What might help in such situations is to disable, uninstall the extension and then install it again in the hope it will create the missing fields and tables.

It is a good idea to make a backup before you disable the extension because there is a high risk of losing data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to CiviCRM and facing a partially configured, broken multi-site configuration I'd recommend you find a [Partner](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) to help you. (Disclosure: I'm one of them - there are many others!).

You need someone to review your current configuration, understand what is broken/incomplete and then come up with a plan to fix it.  That is beyond the scope of what can reasonably be achieved through SE.

Comment: Wow......uh, thanks.....As a non-profit volunteer with no budget, I don't have money to spend on getting help, so I was hoping to find help here.  I've learned a lot about civi over the past few weeks, but I'm still having problems with this issue. Oh well.